# Using jQuery ONLY for animation in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So after spending some time using React (with Redux) I noticed that everything is very good, with the exception of animation.

Sure, React has the ReactCSSTransitionGroup, but in my opinion it's not flexible enough. Just as an example, let's say I want my logo to have a simple bounce animation every 5 seconds, this turns out to be very hard to do since ReactCSSTransitionGroup only animates when the component is mounted and unmounted.

I've also came across the React Motion library, which looks very cool, however for something as simple as bouncing the logo I don't feel it's worth bringing in such a library and adding 10+ lines of code.

So my question for those who are experienced with React, what are your thoughts about using jQuery (together with lets say Animate.css) for animation? I know that going to the DOM is slow and React disencourages this since it's also considered an antipattern, but was wondering if it would be justifiable for this use case? Would the 'penalty' of accessing the real DOM for animation be even noticeable?

**EDIT: the above example was actually not good since it can be done solely with CSS, so let me slightly change it. Imagine that the time between each bounce should be dynamically triggered, rather than the fixed 5s. Basically the point of the question is to know whether or not if for the 'slightly more complicated'animations (ones that CSS3 or CSSTransitionGroup cannot do easily), jQuery would be a good solution - or still, if possible, not use jQuery at all in.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use CSS3 animations if it's something simple like this. You can just add the class to the element and forget about it.

```css
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 70%, 85%, 95%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
    80% {transform: translateY(-30px);}
    90% {transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
.bounce {
    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="bounce">Logo</h1>
```

To set a delay, play around with the keyframes and increase the animation-duration. You'll notice, for example, that nothing's happening from 0% to 70%.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, please see my edited question above. I'll upvote this answer since it's helpful, but can't accept it yet.

Comment: Your clarification changes this into a matter of opinion, rather than something factual. ReactJS is _generally_ used for mobile development, and as such you're gonna want to limit the number of JS libraries you use. With regards to that, why can't you use the React Motion Library over jQuery? Are you already using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I already have JQuery in the project as I'm using some bootstrap plugins which depends on them, I don't use it in my own code. I agree that this question is a matter of opinion, and my intention was to hear the opinion of more experienced developers about this subject.

Comment: Almost any animation you want can be done by adding / removing css classes with animations / transitions. That's generally the best way to do them. With regards to animations with jQuery being an "antipattern", realistically it doesn't matter. As long as your code is maintainable and testable, do whatever it takes to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If using CSS3 animations, you can reduce some boilerplate with [react-animate-on-change](https://github.com/arve0/react-animate-on-change), assuming your state updates when you want the animation to happend. For example a component listening to a redux store.

Usage is like this:

```
// functional component
const Score = (props) =>
  <AnimateOnChange
    baseClassName="Score"
    animationClassName="Score--bounce"
    animate={props.diff != 0}>
      Score: {props.score}
  </AnimateOnChange>
```

Disclaimer, I'm the author.